# PHP Imagick module : imagick module is not available with this php installation in ubuntu

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to install php-imagick to use with laravel intervention image package as its driver, I tried to install it via sudo apt-install php-imagick

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
php-imagick is already the newest version (3.4.3~rc2-2ubuntu4.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

I added extension=imagick.so to my php.ini file and tried restarting the php service with:

```
sudo service php7.3-fpm restart
```

But still getting the same message:

When I do php -m to see installed modules I get this error message:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/imagick.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
```

And when I do convert --version I get this message:

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4 Q16 x86_64 20170114 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2017 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP
Delegates (built-in): bzlib djvu fftw fontconfig freetype jbig jng jpeg lcms lqr ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Imagemagick and Imagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48058369/what-is-the-difference-between-imagemagick-and-imagick)

Comment: not really, the issue is it's not getting recognizedin php modules. I already installed it on ubuntu with sudo apt-get install php-imagick

Comment: The error said `imagick.so` is not found in the particular directories. You could use `find` to locate the file and copy into place.

Comment: I tried find imagick.so but I get :find: ‘imagick.so’: No such file or directory

Comment: `sudo find /usr -name imagick.so` found me `/usr/lib/php/20220829/imagick.so`.

Comment: Interesting, I got the following : /usr/lib/php/20170718/imagick.so , so what should I do now? @Markus Zeller

Comment: Compare your result with the error message and you should notice the versions are not the same.

Comment: I see, but how can I fix it?

Comment: Since `20180731` is newer than the installed version you found, it looks you need to upgrade. https://imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#linux

Comment: You can try to install imagick with `pecl` instead of using apt php-imagick. `pecl install imagick`